# Customizing an ASP.NET MVC 2 site after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, customization

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 site which needs the ability to support custom pages added to the site after deployment. So far, I have created a route for custom pages:

```
routes.MapRoute("Page", "Page/{name}", new { controller = "Custom", action = "Page" });
```

and added a controller action:

```
public ActionResult Page(string name) {
    return View(@"~\Content\Custom\Pages\" + name +".aspx");
}
```

This works fine. It renders whatever page I put in the ~\Content\Custom\Pages folder by name.
The problem is there seems to be no way to add additional code-behind logic to the page unless I embed it in the page itself, and I would like to avoid adding putting back-end logic into a view.

Is there a way to dynamically add a controller without too much fuss?

Any solution needs to be able to survive a deployment update, so modifying `web.config` or any other deployed file is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

At runtime, you can edit the controller page with the necessary code. This wouldn't require any configuration changes as the controller will be recompiled during runtime.

For example:
You can open a new streamwriter and add code to call a model at runtime from the controller

```
string newLine = "\t\tModels." + AppName +
    "DataContext context = new Models." + AppName +
    "DataContext();\n\t\treturn View(context." + AppName + "s);";
result.WriteLine(newLine);
```